# How to "save as" programmatically in R?

Tags: r, save, save-as

I've got a Shiny app that produces a product that I'd like my users to be able to save in whatever location they'd like to save it and with whatever name they'd like. In order to do this, I'm currently using `file.choose` to allow the user to choose a location and file name. On Windows, if it's a new file, the user will be prompted with a message saying this file does not exist and asks if it should be created. On Ubuntu, I believe it was the same outcome. However, this option doesn't work on Mac as there's no way to enter in a new file name and an existing file must be chosen. Additionally, the dialog box says "Open" as opposed to "Save", which is confusing to some users.

Is there a way to trigger the "Save As" dialog box that opens when you save a new file? `save`, `write`, and all other functions either come with a predefined file name or expect one to be passed.

### Edit

I've come across some questions on SO that attempt to address this with the `tcltk` package, but I'm not sure I like this solution since there seem to be some issues on Mac OSX with this package. Others recommended using `choose.files` as there are some customization options you can pass, but this is Windows specific. I'm hoping for a cross-platform option that is intuitive.

Comment: This is a good place to start: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/download-file.html

Comment: @user3949008 Shiny's `downloadHandler` requires that the filename be coded into the source code, either dynamically or statically. But I need the filename to be chosen interactively, so that doesn't quite get me there.

Comment: Hmmm...it allows me to modify the file name and save under the new name even though a placeholder name is specified. Additionally, although I have not used it this specific way, but I believe you can make the filename = function() {} and use user input to create the file name on the fly.

Comment: @user3949008 Interesting. I think you might be on to something then. Let me look into this.